# Slim for WordPress theme development?

Tags: php, ruby, wordpress, sass, slim-lang

[wordless](https://github.com/welaika/wordless) is a fantastic WordPress plugin that brings sanity to WP theme development with solid tools such as HAML and SASS.

Recently we've switched to [**Slim**](http://slim-lang.com) from HAML and I'm very curious as to whether there is a similar option compared to wordless that offers [**Slim**](http://slim-lang.com) instead of HAML?